# Issue displaying divs using show.hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Hi I have some javascript which works in a standalone web page with 5 divs, what it does is when an option is selected it will show a div and hide the others based on drop down selection.Basically what the code does is when a sector is selected on the drop down that corresponding DIV will be displayed eg pubs.

**The problem I am having is in the web page I want this working on I have lots of Div tags and when the page loads all the Divs on the page are hidden, obviously I don't want this.**

Any help would be much appreciated

The code that hides all the divs on page load is

```
$('div').not(name).hide();
```

Is there a way of solving this problem  I cant see how I am going to get round it at the moment.?

JS

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        function showTab( name ) 
        {
        name = '#' + name;

        $('div').not(name).hide();

        $(name).show();
    }

    $('#dropdown').change( function() {

        showTab( $( this ).val() );
    });

    showTab( $('#dropdown').val() );

});
```

HTML

```
<form>
          <p>
          <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
              <option value="Pub-Chains" selected="selected">Pubs </option>
              <option value="Councils">Councils </option>
              <option value="Property">Property </option>
              <option value="Various">Various </option>
              <option value="Universitys">Universitys </option>
          </select>
          </p>
     </form>
```

My Div's are named like so

```
Div id="Pub-Chains"
Div id="Councils"
Div id="Property"
Div id="Various"
Div id="Universitys"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group up the div you want to participate in show hide to separate them from other divs on the page. You can assign a common class to them and use that class to hide them.

```
Div id="Pub-Chains" class="opt"
Div id="Councils" class="opt"
Div id="Property" class="opt"
Div id="Various" class="opt"
Div id="Universitys" class="opt"

$('div.opt').hide();
```

Comment: Hi I think this the right idea I replaced the code that hides all divs with you javascript, but what it does is keep the sector pubs displayed   even when you select other divs.

Comment: You need to show the div as you were doing  

        name = '#' + name;      
        $(name).show();

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function showTab( name ){
       name = '#' + name;
       $(name).siblings().hide(); //<-- hide this way
       $(name).show();
    }
```

and if this is not working then you can do this just put it outside of `doc ready handler`

```
    function showTab( name ){
       name = '#' + name;
       $(name).siblings().hide(); //<-- hide this way
       $(name).show();
    }
   $(document).ready(function () {
   // then all your change stuff here
```

Comment: you can try these two options.

Answer (score 1):

create a parent div to all this div... and call it in selector..

try this

```
<div id="tabdivs">
Div id="Pub-Chains"
Div id="Councils"
Div id="Property"
Div id="Various"
Div id="Universitys"
</div>
```

**jquery**
**updated**

```
$('#tabdivs').children().not(name).hide();
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cTvdM/1/)..

Answer (score 1):

If your target `<div>`s are all siblings then you can easily do something like follows.

```
<div>
  <div id="Pub-Chains">
  <div id="Councils">
  <div id="Property">
  ...
</div>
```

```
$(function(){
  $("select#dropdown").change(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
  }).change();
});
```

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/q4Le6/)

If you have a more complicated layout then you can think of using classnames to group the `<div>` elements.

Comment: sorry where about would this go in my javascript?

Comment: @user1259076, actually you just need that small snippet. I updated the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var ddl = $("#dropdown");
  $('#' + ddl.val()).show().siblings().hide();
  ddl.change(function () {
  $('#' + $(this).val()).fadeIn().siblings().hide();
 });
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SpeWq/)